# Matching strings with constant length?

Tags: regex, perl

Why doesn't the below output both lines?

```
$ cat tmp 
c9::dsk/c9t5000CCA23B2C6A65d0
c10::dsk/c10t5000C50086135011
$ cat tmp | perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /(c\d\d?t[A-Z0-9]{15,16}d0)/'
c9t5000CCA23B2C6A65d0
```

The second `\d` is optional, so it would allow `c10` and the length is between 15 and 16 chars, so that should be fine?

Comment: Remove `d0` at the end, quantifier should be 16-18: `/(c\d\d?t[A-Z0-9]{16,18})/`

Comment: There's nothing in this question about "strings with constant length"!

Comment: This looks like the output from a command-line utility. Please would you explain where it comes from so that the answers will be more useful to other people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why doesn't the below output both lines?

because the second line doesn't end with `d0`, remove that from the pattern.

> the length is between 15 and 16 chars, so that should be fine?

the length of the substring following `c\d\d?t` is 18 and 16 respectively:

```
5000CCA23B2C6A65d0
5000C50086135011
```

So change it to:

```
cat tmp | perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /(c\d\d?t[A-Z0-9]{16,18})/'
```

Comment: I would guess that there are always 16 hex digits after `t` (a 64-bit value), optionally followedby `d0`

Answer (score 2):

I think your data looks like

- `c`
- one or two decimal digits
- `t`
- sixteen hex digits
- optionally, `d0`

A pattern to capture that looks like `/(c\d{1,2}t\p{hex}{16}(?:d0)?)/`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
cat tmp | perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /(c\d+t[A-Z0-9]{16,18}(d0)?)/'
c9t5000CCA23B2C6A65d0
c10t5000C50086135011
```